# Is the Win32 API function definition available in a "database"/XML format?

Tags: database, winapi

I'm looking for a list of win32 API in some "database"/XML format.

I'd need it to easily create a "conversion layer" between win32 API and the higher level language I'm using (harbour/xharbour). Since this runs Pcode, it is necessary to transform  parameters to C standard...

Instead of doing manual code write, I'd like to automate the process...

just for example, the windows API definition (taken from MSDN)

```
DWORD WINAPI GetSysColor(
  __in  int nIndex
);
```

should be transformed in

```
HB_FUNC( GETSYSCOLOR )
{
    hb_retnl( (LONG) GetSysColor( hb_parni( 1 ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, pinvoke.net only stores text data with the PInvoke definition for the call. Not very useful if what you want is something to use as a pre-parsed database of APIs.

Probably you could create an small parser that will take the include file and translate it to what you need. In that case, I'd recommend using [lcc-win32](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/)'s include files, as they are pretty much fat-free/no-BS version of the SDK headers (they don't come with a bunch of special reserved words you'd have to ignore, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you have Microsoft Platform SDK, but it is in raw .h C code, so hard to parse!

Similar work have been done by VB users (and Delphi users and probably for some other languages), for example [ApiViewer](http://www.activevb.de/rubriken/apiviewer/index-apiviewereng.html) has such database, but in some proprietary binary format (.apv extension), so you might have to reverse-engineer it.
Similarly, there is an API-Guide, which was hosted at Allapi.net but the later seems to be a parking site now. It used .api files (again binary-proprietary).

Answer (score 0):

About the closest thing I know of would be: http://pinvoke.net/
Maybe they would share their data with you?
They have a VS tool that accesses this data, so it may be a webservice. You might even be able to sniff that out.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some database (and an app for using it, named "[PInvoke Interop Assistant](https://github.com/jaredpar/pinvoke)") at:

https://github.com/jaredpar/pinvoke/tree/master/StorageGenerator/Data

although I'm not sure what's the license for now — thus [I've asked the authors](https://github.com/jaredpar/pinvoke/issues/19).